# Why isn't 'google.script.run' not working from the html body 'onload' tag?

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I wrote a function for a Google Sheet (in the Sheet's script editor) in which the user selects a cell, runs the function from a custom menu, and then an html form pops up with the text from the selected cell and an adjacent cell in the form.

Here is the 'Code.gs' file:

```
function reviewApplication() {
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Index').setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(html, 'Review PD Application');
}

function getTitleInfo() {
  return SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange().getValue();
}

function getTeacherInfo() {
  var aRow = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange().getRow();
  return SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(aRow, 5).getValue();
}
```

And here is the 'Index.html' file:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <script>
   function onTitle(title) {
     if (title == '') {return; }
     document.getElementById("title").innerHTML = title;
     google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onTeacher).getTeacherInfo();
   }
      
   function onTeacher(name) {
     if (name == '') { return; }
     document.getElementById("teachername").innerHTML = name;
   }
   </script>
 </head>
 <body onload="google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onTitle).getTitleInfo()">
  <form name="myform">
   Title: <a id="title"></a><br>
   Teacher: <a id="teachername"></a><br>
   Decision: 
    <select id="decisionlist" name="decision">
     <option value="blank"></option>
     <option value="Approved">Approved</option>
     <option value="Returned for Review">Returned for Review</option>
     <option value="Not Approved">Not Approved</option>
    </select><br>
   Comments:
    <textarea name="comments" rows="4" cols="50"></textarea><br>
    <input id="button" type="button" value="Submit" onclick="inputOkay(myform.elements['decision'].value, myform.elements['comments'].value)"/>
  </form>
 </body>
</html>
```

The problem is that when the UI pops up with the form, the 'title' and 'teachername' elements of the form are blank, but they are supposed to be populated with the text on that row of the spreadsheet. When I look at the execution transcript, the 'reviewApplication' function runs successfully, but the 'getTitleInfo' function fails and the duration is 0 seconds. Do you know why it is failing at this point?

There's other script code for when the form is submitted, but I'm leaving that out now because I've narrowed the problem down to when the html loads.  Weirdly, this was working fine until last weekend.

Here is an image showing that the 'reviewPD' function runs, but then the 'getTitleInfo' function fails.

[image: Screenshot of Execution Log]

Comment: Other than the quoted duration, What makes you think `getTitleInfo` fails?

Comment: Could you share the spreadsheet or a copy of it?

Comment: @TheMaster, I updated the posted with a screenshot of the execution log showing that 'reviewPD' runs but 'getTitleInfo' then fails each time.  I did what Cooper suggested in the answer (having the getTitleInfo just return a string instead of getting the value from the spreadsheet, but this also does not work. Ultimately, the form that pops up in the UI is blank for the Title and Teacher fields.  So for some reason the onload="google.script.run" isn't working properly.  Could it be a timing thing? Like one process doesn't finish before the other one can start?

Comment: @Kessy, a copy of the Google Sheet is linked below. The user selects the PD Title (column H) and then clicks 'reviewApplication' from a custom add-in menu. So the 'getTitleInfo' function returns the value in the active range (e.g., Math Conference) and then the 'getTeacherInfo' returns the value in column 5 of the active row (the name of the teacher).   https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1esT7v-pAW_Xtxp1G5sHx9GnIHkRvAmiHE-lB72mdwzU/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: If `getTitleInfo()` fails, the execution log would show a reason.  Click on Failed=> a drop down should show. If it doesn't, you need to switch your Google cloud project to a standard one and use stackdriver logging.

Comment: @TheMaster, In the Project Settings of the script editor I unchecked "Enable Chrome V8 runtime" and it now works as it should (as it was previously working).  Thank you!  Any idea why this doesn't work in Chrome V8 runtime? For now, I'm going to keep it unchecked because I need this functionality.

Comment: Have you managed to make it work with V8? Can you update on it?

Answer (score 0):

I did like this and it worked.

GS:

```
function reviewApplication() {
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('ah3');
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(html,'Review PD Application');
}

function getTitleInfo() {
  return 'Teacher Title';
}

function getTeacherInfo() {
  
  return 'Hello World';
}
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <script>
   function onTitle(title) {
     if (title == '') {return; }
     document.getElementById("title").innerHTML = title;
     google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onTeacher).getTeacherInfo();
   }
      
   function onTeacher(name) {
     if (name == '') { return; }
     document.getElementById("teachername").innerHTML = name;
   }
   </script>
 </head>
 <body onload="google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onTitle).getTitleInfo()">
  <form name="myform">
   Title: <a id="title"></a><br>
   Teacher: <a id="teachername"></a><br>
   Decision: 
    <select id="decisionlist" name="decision">
     <option value="blank"></option>
     <option value="Approved">Approved</option>
     <option value="Returned for Review">Returned for Review</option>
     <option value="Not Approved">Not Approved</option>
    </select><br>
   Comments:
    <textarea name="comments" rows="4" cols="50"></textarea><br>
    <input id="button" type="button" value="Submit" onclick="inputOkay(myform.elements['decision'].value, myform.elements['comments'].value)"/>
  </form>
 </body>
</html>
```

Must be something wrong with the way you're getting data.

Try testing getTeacherInfo() or getTeacherInfo() by themselves to maker sure it's working

[image]

**This version actually does the data collection very similar to what you want and it is completely working except I haven't tried the submit because I don't think I have the code to support it.

Code:

```
function reviewApplication() {
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('ah3');
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(html,'Review PD Application');
}

function getTeacherInfo() {
  const ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh=ss.getActiveSheet();
  const row=sh.getActiveRange().getRow();
  return sh.getRange(row,5).getValue();
}

function getTitleInfo() {
  return SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange().getValue();
}
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <script>
   function onTitle(title) {
     if (title == '') {return; }
     document.getElementById("title").innerHTML = title;
     google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onTeacher).getTeacherInfo();
   }
      
   function onTeacher(name) {
     if (name == '') { return; }
     document.getElementById("teachername").innerHTML = name;
   }
   </script>
 </head>
 <body onload="google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onTitle).getTitleInfo()">
  <form name="myform">
   Title: <a id="title"></a><br>
   Teacher: <a id="teachername"></a><br>
   Decision: 
    <select id="decisionlist" name="decision">
     <option value="blank"></option>
     <option value="Approved">Approved</option>
     <option value="Returned for Review">Returned for Review</option>
     <option value="Not Approved">Not Approved</option>
    </select><br>
   Comments:
    <textarea name="comments" rows="4" cols="50"></textarea><br>
    <input id="button" type="button" value="Submit" onclick="inputOkay(myform.elements['decision'].value, myform.elements['comments'].value)"/>
  </form>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I just tried doing what you suggested by returning a string from getTitleInfo and getTeacherInfo (instead of getting the value from the spreadsheet).  But this also doesn't work.  So I think the issue is in the call to getTitleInfo in the first place.  For some reason, the onload="google.script.run" is not successfully calling getTitleInfo.  It's weird because it's working for you and it was previously working for me until last weekend.

Comment: Did you get the correct html file name?I just tried it again and it's working for me.  The name of the html file is 'ah3.html'

Comment: Yes, I got the correct html file name and it imports the html. So the form pops up, it just doesn't have "Teacher Title" and "Hello World" pre-loaded in the form.  And when I check the execution logs, it is just like the image in my original post.  It shows that 'reviewApplication' runs successfully, but 'getTitleInfo' fails.